# How to understand the "row" in Foundation?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am very new to Foundation and am working on my first project.

What i'm not sure that i'm doing well is how i'm using the row class.

Currently i have the following setup:

The point is that i'm using the classes "two",  "eight", "ten", etc to always add every row up to 12, is this the correct thinking about how i'm using the grid system?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from Charles' answer is a correct use, my description is here for the reason behind using a 'row'.

An element with a class of 'row' will create a horizontal block to contain one or more vertical columns. Then add divs with a 'column' or 'columns' class within that row. Specify the widths of each column with the small-#, medium-#, and large-# classes. The use of a 'row' is needed to contain all of your elements which have a size class associated with them.

Comment: This is precisely the kind of reasoning i was looking for thanks Dylan.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use this would be:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="large-2 columns">
     This text spans 2 columns.
   </div>
   <div class="large-8 columns">
     This text spans 8 columns.
   </div>
   <div class="large-2 columns">
     This text spans 2 columns.
   </div>
</div>
```